# Deploying website disables Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7, octopus-deploy

I have a MVC .net website that i deploy using Octopus Deploy to a Windows 2008 server

Every time I Deploy a release the Windows Authentication is set back to Disabled

The test version of the site is also on a different Windows 2008 server but this does not disable the setting.

My gut reaction might be that it IIS thats doing this rather than Octopus but don't want to rule that out at this stage.

Comment: I assume the deploy includes the web.config file which contains the authentication settings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We also had this problem using Octopus Deploy. Deploying to the testing environment went OK, with IIS keeping Windows Authentication = enabled, but when deploying to the dev environment then Windows Authentication was switched to disabled.

The solution for us was to edit the applicationHost.config file in the webserver (under C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config) and add a location-section for the site at the end of the file (but before `</configuration>`) like this:

```
<location path="MyWebSite">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
            </authentication>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

After this, the Windows Authentication setting was kept at enabled after deploy.

Answer (score 3):

It also seems to work to just specify the desired behaviour in the web**Server** part of the web config:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <security >
      <authentication>
        <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
        <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
      </authentication>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to check whether the checkbox for 'Enable Windows Authentication' is checked .

And which version of Octopus deploy you are using .

To get the above options 'Enable Windows Authentication' you need to click on 'configure features' and select 'IIS web site and application pool'

Comment: IIS is already configured on my Server with an Application Pool, as said in my original post, it is when I do a new deploy each time that the Authentication Setting is set back to disabled and have to reset manually to enabled each time.  Octopus Version 2.0

Comment: Check the Web.config, before and after deployment . Do you use the following Key :- <authentication mode="Windows"> in your web.config . IF any other setting is used other than "Windows"for example  <authentication mode="Forms"> , this will automatically disable Windows authentication on IIS upon deployment

Comment: The web.config remains as <authentication mode="Windows" />. As said the site deploys fine to our separate windows 2008 test server and keeps the authentication mode.

Comment: Just trying to help . Since I use Octopus deploy everyday, I am trying to get to the bottom of it so that I am also aware if something is not quite right in octopus . So please bear with me.    
Is it possible for you to upgrade Octopus deploy to latest ? I think this was a bug rHave a look at https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/Issues/issues/1129  .